# stored procedure to get access on all databases/schema/tables/UDF/procedures

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to write a stored procedure with while loop which will list out the databases and in nested loop it will list out all the schemas and again in each schema it will provide read only access to tables/UDF/Procedures to a specified role.
As I am new, I don't know how to use loops/ arrays in Snowflake and how to read arrays.

Comment: What language do you want to use for your stored procedure? We support JavaScript, SQL, Java/Scala.

Comment: What do you mean by read only access to UDF and procedures? The only privs allowed in this case are USAGE (to allow executing proc/udf), ALL, OWNERSHIP. Refer: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/security-access-control-privileges.html#stored-procedure-privileges

Comment: Also consider checking statement for grant ALL - e.g. grant select on all tables in database <DB_NAME> to <ROLE>;